Dragging / Hyperlink Functionality
I've been trying to make  website for a bit now, and I wanted to ask for some help on making this draggable folder that doubles as a hyperlink. I want it to resemble Kendrick Lamar's oklama.com, where you can drag the folders and open them on a direct click. This code lets you drag, but redirects upon release. I'd appreciate any help at all!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #draggable {
      width: 64px;
      height: 56px;
      background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FireMS/nuriel/main/pixelFolder.png');
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #text {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
    <div id="draggable"></div>
  </a>
  <div id="text">nuL</div>

  <script>
    const draggable = document.getElementById('draggable');
    const text = document.getElementById('text');
    updateTextPosition();
    let offsetX, offsetY;
    let isDragging = false;

    draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);
    draggable.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
    draggable.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
    draggable.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);

    function dragStart(event) {
      isDragging = true;
      const clientX = event.type === 'mousedown' ? event.clientX : event.touches[0].clientX;
      const clientY = event.type === 'mousedown' ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].clientY;
      offsetX = clientX - draggable.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      offsetY = clientY - draggable.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function dragEnd() {
      isDragging = false;
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);

    function drag(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        const clientX = event.type === 'mousemove' ? event.clientX : event.touches[0].clientX;
        const clientY = event.type === 'mousemove' ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].clientY;
        draggable.style.left = clientX - offsetX + 'px';
        draggable.style.top = clientY - offsetY + 'px';
        updateTextPosition();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    function updateTextPosition() {
      text.style.left = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
      text.style.top = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 'px';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



I honestly had no clue what approach to take with it, so I asked the major AI's like ChatGPT and Microsoft CoPilot. I just want to be able to drag the folder around, and only redirect upon a direct click.
